# MySQL - query - Mix between DISTINCT and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table:

```
SELECT * FROM tblTemp;
+-----+---------------------+
| id  | timestamp           |
+-----+---------------------+
|  84 | 2013-07-18 22:36:32 |
|  85 | 2013-07-18 22:36:33 |
|  88 | 2013-07-18 22:36:33 |
|  89 | 2013-07-18 22:36:34 |
| 263 | 2013-08-04 16:01:05 |
| 264 | 2013-08-04 16:01:11 |
| 272 | 2013-08-04 16:01:42 |
| 273 | 2013-08-04 16:01:42 |
| 274 | 2013-08-04 16:01:42 |
| 275 | 2013-08-04 16:21:25 |
| 276 | 2013-08-04 16:21:25 |
| 279 | 2013-08-04 16:21:26 |
| 280 | 2013-08-04 16:21:27 |
| 281 | 2013-08-04 16:21:27 |
+-----+---------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

First i want to remove all double timestamps in the view like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM tblTemp;
+---------------------+
| timestamp           |
+---------------------+
| 2013-07-18 22:36:32 |
| 2013-07-18 22:36:33 |
| 2013-07-18 22:36:34 |
| 2013-08-04 16:01:05 |
| 2013-08-04 16:01:11 |
| 2013-08-04 16:01:42 |
| 2013-08-04 16:21:25 |
| 2013-08-04 16:21:26 |
| 2013-08-04 16:21:27 |
+---------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But this is not enough. I need the count, how many entries are in the DB each hour (without doubles) - about this:

```
+---------------------+-------+
| timestamp           | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2013-07-18 22:00:00 | 3     |
| 2013-08-04 16:00:00 | 6     |
+---------------------+-------|
```

First i thought i can use the following command:

```
SELECT timestamp, COUNT(id) FROM tblTemp GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp), MONTH(timestamp), DAY(timestamp), HOUR(timestamp)
```

But it doesn't work fine. The command counts all rows :/

```
+---------------------+-------+
| timestamp           | count |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2013-07-18 22:36:32 |     4 |
| 2013-08-04 16:01:05 |    10 |
+---------------------+-------+
```

It is not important, if the value in column timestamp is 2013-07-18 22:00:00 or 2013-07-18 22:36:32 or anything else as long as the time and date is identifiable.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y %H') AS date_hour, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT timestamp) 
FROM tblTemp 
GROUP BY date_hour
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this (you might need to check the date format string)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y %H') timestamp, COUNT(id) 
FROM tblTemp 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%m/%d/%Y %H')
```

Comment: this won't remove duplicate `timestamp` values

Comment: yea I am missing a distinct..thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H'), count(*)
 from (select distinct `timestamp` from Table1) abc
group by DATE_FORMAT(`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H');
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3756b/8)**